# Mixxx - mixing application abborts/stops loading due to core dump on debian bookworm/sid

Tags: debian, audio, mixxx

The GUI of the program just pops up with a black screen without no content. Then the startup crashes…

Running: `mixxx --logLevel trace`

Outputs:

```
Info [Main]: Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "aif"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   1 : "libsndfile"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "aiff"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   1 : "libsndfile"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "caf"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   1 : "libsndfile"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "flac"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   2 : "Xiph.org libFLAC"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   1 : "libsndfile"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "it"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   2 : "MODPlug"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "med"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   2 : "MODPlug"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "mod"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   2 : "MODPlug"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "mp3"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   2 : "MAD: MPEG Audio Decoder"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "ogg"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   2 : "Xiph.org OggVorbis"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   1 : "libsndfile"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "okt"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   2 : "MODPlug"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "opus"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   2 : "Xiph.org libopusfile"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "s3m"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   2 : "MODPlug"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "stm"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   2 : "MODPlug"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "wav"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   1 : "libsndfile"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy - SoundSource providers for file extension "xm"
Info [Main]: SoundSourceProxy -   2 : "MODPlug"
Debug [Main]: "Mixxx" "2.2.4" "(flags: asan=0 asmlib=0 battery=1 buildtime=0 bulk=1 color=0 coreaudio=0 faad=0 ffmpeg=0 hid=1 hss1394=0 ipod=0 lilv=1 localecompare=1 macappstore=0 mad=1 mediafoundation=0 modplug=1 opengles=0 optimize=portable opus=1 perftools=0 perftools_profiler=0 profiling=0 qt_sqlite_plugin=0 qtkeychain=0 shoutcast=1 test=False tsan=0 ubsan=0 vamp=1 verbose=1 vinylcontrol=1 wv=0)" is starting...
Debug [Main]: Compile time library versions:
Debug [Main]: Qt: 5.15.2
Debug [Main]: libshout: 2.4.5
Debug [Main]: PortAudio: 1246720 PortAudio V19.6.0-devel, revision 396fe4b6699ae929d3a685b3ef8a7e97396139a4
Debug [Main]: RubberBand: 1.8.2
Debug [Main]: SoundTouch: 2.1.2
Debug [Main]: TagLib: 1.11.1
Debug [Main]: ChromaPrint: 1.5.0
Debug [Main]: Vorbis: Xiph.Org libVorbis 1.3.7
Debug [Main]: libsndfile: libsndfile-1.0.31
Debug [Main]: FLAC: 1.3.3
Debug [Main]: QDesktopServices::storageLocation(HomeLocation): "/home/nathanael"
Debug [Main]: QDesktopServices::storageLocation(DataLocation): "/home/nathanael/.local/share/data//Mixxx"
Debug [Main]: QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() "/usr/bin"
Debug [Main]: Loading resources from  "/usr/share/mixxx/"
Warning [Main]: Configuration file is at version "2.1.5" instead of the current 2.2.4
Info [Main]: BroadcastSettings - Found 1 profile(s)
Debug [Main]: Loading resources from  "/usr/share/mixxx/"
Debug [Main]: Loading resources from  "/usr/share/mixxx/"
Debug [Main]: Loading translations for locale "de" from translations folder "/usr/share/mixxx/translations/" : success
Debug [Main]: "Error: Unable to import console: no such extension"
Debug [Main]: "Error: Unable to import svg: no such extension"
Debug [Main]: Loading resources from  "/usr/share/mixxx/"
Debug [Main]: Compressor attack per frame:  0.000408163 decay per frame:  4.08163e-05
no more csLADSPA plugins
lo server running on 14742
Warning: failed to load part<>!
mixxx: src/freeverb/revmodel.cpp:37: void revmodel::setrate(int): Assertion `rate <= TUNING_MAX_SAMPLE_RATE' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Mixxx version: `2.2.4~dfsg-1`

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid   
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-1-686-pae
    Architecture: x86
 Hardware Vendor: Lenovo
  Hardware Model: Rev 1.0
     GNOME Shell: 41.1
```

**For all suggested solutions: *Thanks in advance!***

Comment: it probably worth raising this with the mixxx team directly 
https://mixxx.org/support/

Answer (score 0):

Part of running testing/unstable is installing the debug packages and attaching the debugger to the program. If you don't know how to do that, just report a bug to Debian. `$ reportbug`